# How can we deploy vespa application on multiple docker running on separate instances?

Tags: docker, vespa

I need to deploy Vespa on multiple instances (3) using docker. What configuration changes do I have to do in my application package or in docker so that I can run the admin node, container node, content node on separate instances?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out the [Docker Swarm example](https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/basic-search-on-docker-swarm) in the documentation? For a more manual approach, you can look at the [Multi-Node Quick Start for AWS EC2](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/vespa-quick-start-multinode-aws.html#configure-and-deploy) as this shows an example for multi-node (instance) config that should be applicable in your case.